# Emacs flycheck add include directory, no flycheck-gcc-*

Tags: flycheck

emacs version:

> GNU Emacs 24.3.1 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.10.7) of
>   2014-03-07 on lamiak, modified by Debian

M-x flycheck version:

> Flycheck version: 0.25alpha (package: 20150821.47)

M-x flycheck-verify-setup:

> Syntax checkers for buffer file.c in c-mode:
>
> c/c++-clang
>       - predicate:  nil
>       - executable: Not found
>
> c/c++-gcc
>       - predicate:  t
>       - executable: Found at /usr/bin/gcc
>
> c/c++-cppcheck
>       - predicate:  t
>       - executable: Found at /usr/bin/cppcheck
>
> Flycheck Mode is enabled.

M-x flycheck-gcc-include

> [NO MATCH]

How can I enable flycheck-gcc-* commands to define inc dirs?

Comment: I wonder how you got the idea that `flycheck-gcc-include-path` was a command.  It's not, and it's nowhere documented as such…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`flycheck-gcc-include-path` is a *variable*, not a command.  You can change it globally with `M-x customize-variable RET flycheck-gcc-include-path`, or per file or directory with [File Variables](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/File-Variables.html) and [Directory Variables](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Directory-Variables.html#Directory-Variables) respectively.